# how to get number of files in a directory using c++ program on windows commands

Tags: c++, windows, command

I have some N number of images(pictures) in a file.I want to get number images in that file and store that number to another file. I want all these to be done through C++ code on Windows
using windows commands with system();

Can any one Help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. Also be specific. The title and question do not ask for the same thing. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) in which you'll count the number of files instead of printing the names.